# Publishing message to the SQS in china region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to write message to SQS queue(in china region) from the host(in US region), is it possible to do that? Or do i have to create host in china region only to publish the message to SQS located in china region.

Comment: You can specify the region, and appropriate AWS credentials, to the AWS CLI or SDK. You would need to specify what exactly you are using (CLI, or which one of the SDKs) for us to provide an actual code sample.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Assuming the SQS endpoint -- which appears to be https://sqs.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn -- is accessible from the Internet (as appears to be the case), and and you have a set of credentials from AWS China, it should work from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing `SQS` across regions is possible via correct `IAM` permissions and most importantly the `SQS URL` that you need to supply to your `AWS SDK`.

Here you can find more information about [Queue and Message Identifiers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/ImportantIdentifiers.html).

Here's an example of a policy that could be applied to a queue to give an IAM user called `SQSUser` permissions on that queue:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123123123123:default_staging/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Sid89345945989988",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:user/SQSUser"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123123123123:default_staging"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the significant part as SQSUser is your user in China:

```
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:user/SQSUser"
      },
```

Comment: I think you'll find that AWS China ARNs are in a [different service partition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#genref-arns), specifically `arn:aws-cn:...` and as far as I know, China runs an independent, isolated IAM system.